# How can I make the backspace key delete one character backwards in tcsh?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tcsh

I have a clean installation of openSuse.  This automatically sets up bash as the default shell.

For historic reasons, all of the aliases and shortcuts I want to port from an old computer are in tcsh, and I don't really feel up to learning how to do the same in bash.  Instead, I changed the login shell to tcsh, and I'm happy.

The problem I have now is that backspace only deletes forward (like the <kbd>del</kbd> key), instead of backward (like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>).  How can I bind the backspace key to delete backwards instead of forward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell command to change key bindings is `bindkey`, <kbd>Backspace</kbd> presumably sends byte 127 (`^?`; check by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>Backspace</kbd>), and the edition command to delete a character backwards is `backward-delete-char`. So put this in your `~/.tcshrc`:

```
bindkey '^?' backward-delete-char
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# stty erase <press backspace key>
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work.

Comment: This might work dependent on terminal and previous configuration. I have used `stty erase '0x7f'` in the past as a fix. Entering the key '^?' with `Ctrl` + `V` then `Backspace` could also work. Simply pressing backspace might not work as intended as it can output other characters to the command-line.